# Fix for RunUAT.bat

Tags: azure-devops, compilation, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines, unreal-engine4

How can we fix it, we used `RunUAT.bat BuildCookRun -project="E:\agent\_work\1\s\P1.uproject" -clientconfig=Development -platform=Win64 -cook -stage -pak -stagingdirectory="E:\agent\_work\1\s\" -package -build` to compile our game with Azure Pipeline but we have this error https://imgur.com/a/37lfR5j one more thing we are not going to supply .uproject in game folder because we want to sell this game

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to your unreal project. And you used your private agent to build this project under azure devops pipeline.

Try these:

**1)** remove `win64` platform configuration under command

**2)** update or reinstall unreal enigne on the pricate agent

**3)** or you could re-name the project to `xxx-Win32-Shipping.exe` or `xxx-Win64-Shipping.exe`.

**Besides**, you could report the issue on [Unreal Engine forum](https://forums.unrealengine.com/).

Comment: So, I have tried 2nd and 3rd option but it doesn't work I am still getting the same error ```Failed to open descriptor file ./../.Workstation/P1.uproject``` I really don't know what to do It was working before, I even tried the first 2 build and I'm still getting the same error, I have planned releasing this game on holiday